# Using a zsh array in a case ststement

Tags: zsh

I am having trouble with using a case statement to return months.
It feels so obvious I'm not sure why its stumping me so well!

```bash
month=(01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12)
case ${month[@]} in
   test ${month[@]:8:1} = $(date +%m))
   RPROMPT='September %D{%d %Y} %@'
   ;;
   *)
   RPROMPT='%D{%b %d, %Y} %@'
   ;;
esac
```

Yes. I do want the full name of the months, not just a three-letter abbreviation.

It's also a good refresher as I've not touch shell-script in years.

It returns the `*)` case.

Comment: The syntax is wrong (see harrymc's answer or have a look at https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#index-case-selection)
If you want to include the month in your prompt, why not just something like that: `month=(January February March April May June July August September ...); RPROMPT="$month[$(date +%m)]"` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the array and apply the case statement to each
element in turn:

```
for element in "${month[@]}"; do
  case ${element} in
```

Comment: Why? I wrote the code like I did to avoid looping and so I could just call `${month[@]:8:1}` or `${month[@]:2:1}` and just set a case to September or February.

Comment: so I could make a case statement and then call `${month[@]:8:1}` and print "September". I do have an `if` statement that works but I thought a `case` statement would be more appropriate for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: you can't just test for equality? `test ${month[@]:8:1} = $(date +%m))` This should test if `09 = 09` without need for a loop or if statement.
As it is presently as September.